# how to convert data into list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a sample `dataset A` that looks like this:

```
1:CH,AG,ME,GS;AP,CH;HE,AC;AC,AG
2:CA;HE,AT;AT,AC;AT,OG
3:NE,AG,AC;CS,OD
```

The expected result should be:

```
['CH','AG','ME','GS','AP','CH','HE','AC','AC','AG','CA','HE','AT','AT','AC','AT','OG','NE','AG','AC','CS','OD']
```

I am not sure how to write the code in Python to a list.

Comment: Have you tried anything to try to solve this problem? Can you show your code for this and explain what difficulties you are having in your implementation?

Comment: `with open('path/to/file') as infile: data = [i for sub in [line.split(":",1)[1].replace(';',',').split(',') for line in infile] for i in sub]`

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to locate all 2 consecutive upper-case letter cases with a regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: data = """
   ...: 1:CH,AG,ME,GS;AP,CH;HE,AC;AC,AG
   ...: 2:CA;HE,AT;AT,AC;AT,OG
   ...: 3:NE,AG,AC;CS,OD"""

In [3]: re.findall(r"[A-Z]{2}", data, re.MULTILINE)
Out[3]: 
['CH',
 'AG',
 'ME',
 'GS',
 'AP',
 'CH',
 'HE',
 'AC',
 'AC',
 'AG',
 'CA',
 'HE',
 'AT',
 'AT',
 'AC',
 'AT',
 'OG',
 'NE',
 'AG',
 'AC',
 'CS',
 'OD']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if Python 2.7

---

```
a = "CH,AG,ME,GS;AP,CH;HE,AC;AC,AG"
b = "CA;HE,AT;AT,AC;AT,OG"
c = "NE,AG,AC;CS,OD"
d = a+','+b+','+c
d = d.replace(';',',')
print d.split(',')    #output as expected
```

---